# Unable to retrieve single value from array of values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to retrieve a value to do a String comparison test and I can't seem to retrieve the single value from an array of values.  Here's my code:

```
function CoverageCalculator() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var searchRange = sheet.getRange('D3:D20')
  var rangeValues = searchRange.getValues();

  var Test = searchRange[1][1];
}
```

In debug mode, "Test" is undefined, any ideas on why this might be the case?

Comment: Shouldn't it be rangeValues[1][1]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
var Test = searchRange[1][1];
```

to

```
var Test = rangeValues[1][0];
```

The above because `searchRange` is a Range object, not an array, but `rangeValues` it's. Regarding the indexes, the first one determines the row, and the second the column and considering that the source range is D3:D20 the resulting array has 17 rows high and 1 column width, then the maximum valid index for the second index is 0.

Comment: Ah, yes. Typo on my part, though rangValues still returns an undefined

Comment: Since it's an array of width 1 (I think that's the right terminology?) ie, a column vector, I just need to declare an element, not a [row][column]

So, 

var Test = rangeValues[1]; works  Thank you!